# How to get a dictionary of `field_name:field_type` from pandas DF

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, types

I'm trying to create a simple dictionary of field and field types from a given Dataframe (format: `field_name:field_type`)

For example, i have this DF.dtypes:

```
1. name                                 object
2. On_Time                              object
3. On_Budget                            object
4. actual_hr                            float64
5. Baseline_Start_Date                  datetime64[ns]
6. Forecast_Start_Date                  datetime64[ns]
```

I would like to run a function that will return the desired dictionary:

```
{'NAME':'object', 'On_Time':'object', 'On_Budget':'object', 'actual_hr':'float64', 'Forecast_Start_Date':'datetime64[ns]', 'actual_hr':'datetime64[ns]'}
```

Comment: Try df.to_dict('records')

Answer (score 3):

Try using `dtypes` to a dictionary using `.to_dict()`:

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> df=pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,2,3],'b':['a','b','c']})
>>> {k:str(v[0]) for k,v in pd.DataFrame(df.dtypes).T.to_dict('list').items()}
{'a': 'int64', 'b': 'object'}
```

Answer (score 3):

Convert [`DataFrame.dtypes`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.dtypes.html) to strings by [`astype`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.astype.html) and then `Series` [`to_dict`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.to_dict.html):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':list('abcdef'),
                   'date':pd.date_range('2015-01-01', periods=6),
                   'Wgt':[5.1,3,6,9,2,4],})

print (df)
   A      dated  Wgt
0  a 2015-01-01  5.1
1  b 2015-01-02  3.0
2  c 2015-01-03  6.0
3  d 2015-01-04  9.0
4  e 2015-01-05  2.0
5  f 2015-01-06  4.0

print (df.dtypes.astype(str).to_dict())
{'A': 'object', 'date': 'datetime64[ns]', 'Wgt': 'float64'}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try, `df.to_dict('records')`

According to pandas documentation, `to_dict` has the following parameters

> str {‘dict’, ‘list’, ‘series’, ‘split’, ‘records’, ‘index’}

Determines the type of the values of the dictionary.

1. ‘dict’ (default) : dict like {column -> {index -> value}}
2. ‘list’ : dict like {column -> [values]}
3. ‘series’ : dict like {column -> Series(values)}
4. ‘split’ : dict like {‘index’ -> [index], ‘columns’ -> [columns], ‘data’ -> [values]}
5. ‘records’ : list like [{column -> value}, … , {column -> value}]
6. ‘index’ : dict like {index -> {column -> value}}